Map P-Dropdown Option to matching option or default label if non existent
I'm passing an object into a child component with data to populate a p-dropdown. Currently the dropdown is being populated by an enum of available options, however, there are 2 use cases.
The first would be if the variable contains "" the default label "Select a city" option should be the dropdown option.
The second would be if the variable contains anything else that should be the currently selected option. If it matches a possible value in the enum to use that, else it should append the city to the dropdown list so there aren't duplicate options.
Here's my code so far:
export class Citys{
     @Input() city: String;
     cityOptions: CityEnum[] = Object.values(CityEnum);
     chosenCity: string;
}

<div>
   <p-dropdown [options]="cityOptions" [(ngModel)]="chosenCity" placeholder="Select a City"
   </p-dropdown>
</div>

export enum CityEnum{
   LON = "London",
   PAR = "Paris",
   VIE = "Vienna"
}

I've tried adding the input to the list as a variable in the place holder but that also is accounting for the value already existing within the enum.

I was actually able to figure it out and the answer was right in my face. Instead of having the array of the enum type, I could have it as a string array since I was already getting the values and simply append the option to the option list.
